# gcc /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglut32, -lopengl32, -lglu32, -lfreegut, but these are installed

Tags: linux, gcc, c, opengl, solus

I'm trying to compile a demo project, what is using `OpenGL`.
I'm getting this error message:
[image: Everything is missing, at least gcc says it]

But I have everything:

[image: but I have everything]

What is happening? 
If I have all of the dependencies, why does it not compile?

I use Solus 3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The meaning of `-lglut32` (as an example) is, load the library `glut32`.

The result of the `ls` you execute showed that you have the **header file** for `glut32`

In order to solve the problem of *cannot find -l-library-name*

You need:

1. To actually have the library in your computer
2. Help gcc/the linker to find the library by providing the path to the library

   - You can add `-Ldir-name` to the  `gcc` command
   - You can the library location to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable
3. Update the "[Dynamic Linker](https://www.lifewire.com/ldconfig-linux-command-4093742)":

   ```
   sudo ldconfig
   ```

---

[man gcc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)

> ```
> -llibrary
> -l library
>     Search the library named library when linking. 
> -Ldir
>     Add directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for -l.
> ```